# Dynamic inputs path from command line using -E Option in filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Previously, I have used filebeat 5.4.0 and able to set the filebeat input path dynamically by modifying the install-service-filebeat script like this, and it was working fine.

New-Service -name filebeat `-displayName filebeat`
        -binaryPathName "`"$workdir\filebeat.exe`" -c `"$workdir\filebeat.yml`" -E `"filebeat.prospectors.0.paths=[`"$filebeat_input_path`"]`" -path.home `"$workdir`" -path.data `"$workdir`""

Now, we are planning to upgrade to latest ELK stack (v6.5.2), and the above configuration doesn't seems to work.

**NOTE**: i have tried changing 'filebeat.prospectors.0.paths' to 'filebeat.inputs.0.paths', but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to solve the issue by using the filebeat version 6.5.2 with the below filebeat configuration

filebeat.exe" -c "filebeat.yml" -E "filebeat.inputs.0.paths=                       ["D:\logs\server*.log","D:\service\logs*.log"]"